# Dynamic Array as Class Property in VBScript

Tags: arrays, class, vbscript, dynamic-arrays

I am very new to VBScript, and not entirely sure if what I am doing is right.

I want to create a structure to hold onto a string and then an array of strings. The array of string will be dynamic, as I do not know how many entries are going to be in that list.

I have the following:

```
Class ExportMappings
    Private _process_definition
    Private _export_mappings : Set _export_mappings = CreateObject("System.Collection.ArrayList")

    Public Property Let ProcessDefinition(procDef)
        _process_definition= procDef
    End Property

    Public Property Get ProcessDefinition()
        ProcessDefinition = _process_definition
    End Property

    Public Property Let ExportMappings(export)
        _export_mappings = export
    End Property

    Public Sub AddMapping(map)
        _export_mappings.Add map
    End Sub    
End Class
```

First, I am not sure if I declared the _export_mapping array properly.
Secondly, I do not know if I need a constructor to initialize my _export_mappings to an initial size. If so, I do not know how I would do that. 
Lastly, my get and set methods for ExportMapping, I am not sure if that will work.

I would try to run it through a debugger, but the software I am using does not have the best debugger, and usually gives me a very vague description of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

1. VBScript variable names can't start with _; you can 'legalize' invalid names by putting them in [], but for starters I wouldn't do this
2. Code in Classes is allowed in methods only; your `Private _export_mappings : Set _export_mappings = CreateObject("System.Collection.ArrayList")` is invalid

After these changes, your code should compile. If you add code showing how you'd like to use this class, I'm willing to talk about second things (maybe tomorrow).